# A box contains 5 balls marked with number 1, 3 balls marked with number 3 and 2 balls marked with number 9.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, combinations

A box contains $5$ balls marked with number $1, 3$ balls marked with number $3$ and $2$ balls marked with number $9$. We randomly select a ball $100$ times. What is the probability that the product of the numbers on the selected 100 balls is between $3^{60}$ and $3^{100}$?

I am having a hard time solving this question. I noticed that $1=3^0$, $3=3^1$ and $9=3^2$, so I tried finding the probability that the sum is between $60$ and $100$, but I don't know how to calculate it.

Comment: The power of $3$ in the product can randomly vary between $0$ and $200$. So the probability that it will vary between $60$ and $100$ is $\frac{100-60}{200-0}=\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: @L-- Unfortunately, it won't be uniform. For instance, $200$ has probability $(1/5)^{100}$, while $0$ has probability $(1/2)^{100}$. So it's not that easy.

Comment: Based on simulation, the probability seems to be about $0.91$

Comment: @Arthur Right, My mistake. The number of balls are different.

Comment: @L-- Even if there were one of each ball (or any equal amount), $1$ would be 100 times more likely than $0$. And $2$ would be about 50 times more likely than that again.

Comment: Do you require an exact answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't require an exact answer, then the central limit theorem is our friend.

It says, more or less, that the sum of many independent, identically distributed random variables is roughly normal distributed.

The result of a single ball selection (focusing on the exponent rather than the number) has a mean of $0.7$, and a variance of $0.61$. The sum of a hundred of them will have mean $100\cdot 0.7 = 70$ and variance $100\cdot 0.61 = 61$, and it will be roughly normal distributed.

So, the probability ends up being [about $0.9$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=probability+60%3Cx%3C100%2C++x%7Enormal+with+mean+70%2C+variance+61). Depending on whether you include $60$ or $100$ as successful results, you should change the limits in that query to $59.5$ or $60.5$ and $99.5$ or $100.5$ respectively. That changes the result slightly ($0.91$ for the inclusive case, and $0.89$ for the non-inclusive case).